# Why does only one transaction go through, and the rest fails with 'NONCE_ALREADY_USED' error?

Tags: typescript, electron, ethereum, web3js, nonce

I do automation of token exchange for multiple wallets

Stack: Electron, Web3JS, TypeScript

When I run the function, exactly one wallet passes, regardless of the number, the rest fails with an error NONCE_ALREADY_USED

And fails, as I understand it, or random one of them, or the first one by speed (when I replace map to for, passes exactly the first)

One of the wallets:
https://polygonscan.com/address/0xf9c8598c0b90ac6fd3f6cde535146ba3eb5b9026

Failure transaction:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xabbfe55684e6f417d529dbc77ffdef7864f0020e4ed17ed0741e8c2baf6fe765

It seems that Nonce on transactions is correct, but still gives error

And if isTokenNative = false, checkAndApproove function runs absolutely for all wallets without problems, but when it comes to the main transaction, there is an error

Code:

```
const promises = mnemonics.map(async (mnemonic, index): Promise => { const { privateKey } = ethers.Wallet.fromPhrase(mnemonic); const account = // @ts-ignore web3s[chainID].eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);`
          const chain = Object.values(chains).find(
            (chainOne) => chainOne.network === network
          );
    
          // @ts-ignore
          const nonce = await web3s[chainID].eth.getTransactionCount(
            account.address,
            'pending'
          );
    
          await delay(
            parseInt(timeoutRandomMin, 10),
            parseInt(timeoutRandomMax, 10)
          );
    
          if (txData) {
            const isTokenNative = sourceToken === chain?.tokens?.eth.address;
    
            if (!isTokenNative) {
              await checkAndApprove({
                spender: txData.to,
                tokenAddress: sourceToken,
                value: sourceAmount,
                account,
                chainID,
                mnemonic,
                mnemonicID: index,
                nonce,
              });
            }
            // @ts-ignore
            const gasPrice = await web3s[chainID].eth.getGasPrice();
            console.log(isTokenNative);
            const nonceForMainTX = isTokenNative ? nonce : nonce + 1;
    
            const tx = {
              to: txData.to,
              data: txData.data,
              // @ts-ignore
              value: isTokenNative ? web3s[chainID].utils.toHex(sourceAmount) : 0,
              gas: txData.maxGas,
              gasPrice,
              nonce: nonceForMainTX,
            };
    
            try {
              const signedTx = await account.signTransaction(tx);
              console.log(tx.nonce, account.address);
              if (signedTx.rawTransaction != null) {
                // @ts-ignore
                const receipt = await web3s[chainID].eth.sendSignedTransaction(
                  signedTx.rawTransaction
                );
                const time = getTimeForLog();
    
                if (receipt.status) {
                  store.dispatch(
                    addLogEntry(
                      logSuccessWithAddressAndHash(
                        time,
                        'Success',
                        `tx:`,
                        chainID,
                        account.address,
                        signedTx.transactionHash
                      )
                    )
                  );
                } else {
                  const failedTransactions =
                    store.getState().failedTx.failedTransactions || [];
    
                  if (!failedTransactions.includes(mnemonic)) {
                    store.dispatch(addFailedMnemonic(failedTransactions, mnemonic));
                  }
    
                  store.dispatch(
                    addLogEntry(
                      logFailedWithAddressAndHash(
                        time,
                        `Fail`,
                        `tx:`,
                        chainID,
                        account.address,
                        signedTx.transactionHash
                      )
                    )
                  );
                }
              }
            } catch (error) {
              const time = getTimeForLog();
              // @ts-ignore
              const errorMessage = error.message || error;
              const failedTransactions =
                store.getState().failedTx.failedTransactions || [];
    
              if (!failedTransactions.includes(mnemonic)) {
                store.dispatch(addFailedMnemonic(failedTransactions, mnemonic));
              }
    
              store.dispatch(
                addLogEntry(
                  logFailedWithAddress(
                    time,
                    `Fail`,
                    `error: ${errorMessage}`,
                    chainID,
                    account.address
                  )
                )
              );
            }
          } else {
            const time = getTimeForLog();
            const failedTransactions =
              store.getState().failedTx.failedTransactions || [];
    
            if (!failedTransactions.includes(mnemonic)) {
              store.dispatch(addFailedMnemonic(failedTransactions, mnemonic));
            }
    
            store.dispatch(
              addLogEntry(
                logError(time, `Error`)
              )
            );
          }
        });
    
        await Promise.all(promises);
```

Tried running it with a for loop, changing the rpc and making a separate array with nonce for purses